# Hide section separator in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I use this for hiding separator between rows

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

but, there is still separator on top of section header. How can I hide them too?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear
```

It should work

Comment: This is not a good solution . Like If i want to hide specific section then this not working

Answer (score 1):

**With Storyboard:**

[image]

**Without Storyboard:**

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```